# If $A$ is an invertible matrix, do we have $\lVert A x \rVert \geq (\lVert A \rVert -\epsilon)\lVert x \rVert$ for all small $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

The question is as in the title.

Let $A$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and $\lVert x \rVert$ be the Euclidean norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, let $\lVert A \rVert$ be the matrix norm of $A$ with respect to the Euclidean norm.

Then, I wonder if it is possible to have $r_{\epsilon}>0$ for each $\epsilon>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lVert A x \rVert \geq (\lVert A \rVert -\epsilon)\lVert x \rVert
\end{equation}
when $\lVert x \rVert < r_{\epsilon}$.

The above estimate certainly does NOT seem to work when $A$ is NOT invertible. However, I wonder what would happen if $A$ is assumed to be invertible.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: This is possible if and only if $A$ is a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix in which case $\|Ax\| = \|A\|\|x\|$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What *is* true, as a lower bound on $\lVert Ax \rVert$, is: $\lVert Ax \rVert \ge \lVert A^{-1} \rVert^{-1} \cdot \lVert x \rVert$.

Comment: Where did that linked question come from? There is no link in any of the posts here or there.

Comment: Maybe it's delayed, and the link will eventually disappear. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/questions-not-removed-from-linked-when-comments-are-deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x$ to be proportional to the singular vector of $A$ corresponding to the smallest singular value, $\sigma_{\text{min}}$.

Then
$
\|Ax\| = \sigma_{\text{min}}\|x\|.
$
You need
$$
\sigma_{\text{min}}\|x\| \geq (\|A\| - \epsilon)\|x\| \geq (\sigma_{\text{max}} - \epsilon)\|x\|.
$$
You want this to be true for all $x$ up to a certain norm. However, note that the norm of $x$ does not matter in this example. Only the difference between singular values does. Could it possibly be true?

Comment: Oh thank you for your insight..

Comment: So I guess I can get the estimate I want regardless of the norm if $x$ is proportional to the singular vector of highest singular value...

Comment: In that case, the bound holds trivially, yes.